# jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "name" SOLVED

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash, jq

I'm trying to make a JSON collection of country, region, city, org, ip of intrusion attempts.

My JSON test info:

```
[
  {
    "total": 0,
    "country": [
      {
        "name": "CN",
        "nr": 0,
        "region": [
          {
            "name": "Beijing",
            "nr": 0,
            "City": [
              {
                "name": "Haidian",
                "nr": 0,
                "Organisation": [
                  {
                    "name": "AS45090 Shenzhen Tencent Computer Systems Company Limited",
                    "nr": 0,
                    "IPS": [
                      {
                        "192.144.207.22": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "NL",
        "nr": 0,
        "region": [
          {
            "name": "Noord Holland",
            "nr": 0,
            "City": [
              {
                "name": "Amsterdam",
                "nr": 0,
                "Organisation": [
                  {
                    "name": "FEAS",
                    "nr": 0,
                    "IPS": [
                      {
                        "192.162.1.1": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

I load the existing json (test) string into `$geoInfo`. Now i'm trying to change the nr value in the object where`"name": "CN"`

i have tested two sollutions:

`geoInfo="$( jq --arg country ${tmpGeo[0]} --arg count $count -r '.country | map( if .name == $country then . + { .nr=$count } else . end )'<<<"${geoInfo}" )"`

And

`geoInfo="$( jq --arg country ${tmpGeo[0]} --arg count $count -r '.country | select(.[].name == "CN") | .nr) = $count'<<<"${geoInfo}" )"`

With both solutions I get:
`jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "name"`

I use jq version 1.6.

What is going wrong?

Comment: What are the contents of `tmpGeo`? `count`? Show us an exact input you have an output expected to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Just forget all of this! I'm terribly sorry. The errors i got was for a statement in the else section and I was changing the query in the then section. Probably worked to long on the code yesterday. my first solution had a small mistake after changing the `.nr=` to  `"nr":` it worked:

geoInfo="$( jq --arg country ${tmpGeo[0]} --arg count $count -r '.country | map( if .name == $country then . + { "nr": $count } else . end )'<<<"${geoInfo}" )"

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
geoInfo=$(jq "(.[].country[] | select(.name == \"CN\") | .nr) = 1" <<<"$geoInfo")
```